# Recently modified files....listed by size?

Tags: linux

How can I find files/folders that were modified w/in the last 2 days and order them by size?

I have: find . -mtime -2

thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for regular files:

```
find .  -mtime -2  -type f| xargs ls -al | sort -n -k 5
```

This seems to work for folders too:

```
find .  -mtime -2 | xargs ls -al -d | sort -n -k 5
```

Comment: Nice work beduin, but I'll save you an awk. Sort also takes a key param, indicating which field to sort by. So:

#Sort by the fifth delimited field (which is size)
> find .  -mtime -20  -type f | xargs ls -al | sort -n -k 5